# How to implement caching on Google Cloud Storage as Laravel File System which has private objects

Tags: php, laravel, redis, google-cloud-storage, memcached

I am using Google Cloud Storage(GCS) as a Filesystem in my Laravel application. The objects in my GCS bucket are not publicly accessible. Here is my code -:

**Config -:**
*filesystems.php*

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
    | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
    | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
    |
    */

    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 'gcs'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],
        
        'gcs' => [
            'driver' => 'gcs',
            'project_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID'),
            'key_file' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILE'),
            'bucket' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET'),
            'cache' => [
                'store' => 'file',
                'expire' => 600,
                'prefix' => 'cache-prefix',
            ],
        ]

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

**Service Provider -:**
*GoogleStorageServiceProvider.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Storage;
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use Superbalist\Flysystem\GoogleStorage\GoogleStorageAdapter;

class GoogleStorageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Storage::extend('gcs', function($app, $config) {
            
            $storageClient = new StorageClient([
                'projectId' => $config['project_id'],
                'keyFilePath' => $config['key_file'],
            ]);
            
            $bucket = $storageClient->bucket($config['bucket']);

            $adapter = new GoogleStorageAdapter($storageClient, $bucket);

            return new Filesystem($adapter);
            
        });
    }
}
```

**Routes -:**
*web.php*

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\FileController;

//File Access Routes
Route::get('cloud/storage/{file}', [
    FileController::class, 'cloudStorageServe'
])->where(['file' => '.*']);
```

**Controller-:**
*FileController.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function cloudStorageServe($file) {

        if(!Storage::disk('gcs')->exists($file)) { 
            abort('404'); // we redirect to 404 page if it doesn't exist
        }

        $cache_hours = 1;

        return Cache::remember($file, 3600 * $cache_hours, function () use ($cache_hours, $file) {
            return Storage::disk('gcs')->temporaryUrl(
                $file, now()->addMinutes(60 * $cache_hours + 1)
            );
        });
    }
}
```

The objects are being served alright but each page load causes the objects themselves to load again and again. I can't set metadata cache-control response headers on GCS as these objects cannot be publicly accessible. Is there any way to cache the filesystem for at least the images?

Thanks. :)

**EDIT -:**
filesystems.php and FileController.php have been modified to use file store as cache.. still not working

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#caching

Comment: how do I then set up the cache?

Comment: If you set `'store' => 'file'` then Laravel will just use the local file system as a cache. If you want to use other cache drivers then you can read about that in the appropriate section in the manual. If you intend to use Laravel reading the manual is generally a good plan because questions who have their answers in the manual tend to not be well received

Comment: I have edited the code accordingly above, still not working.. :(
In fact, now it's not even loading the images..